# Mac App Rejected by Apple due to Entitlements related to Maps

Tags: objective-c, macos, app-store, entitlements

Please note that i have not used map anywhere in my app but still my app got rejected twice from app store with below error:

From Apple

```
2. 4 Performance: Hardware Compatability
```

Performance - 2.4.5

Your app still uses one or more entitlements which do not have matching functionality within the app. Apps should have only the minimum set of entitlements necessary for the app to function properly. Please remove all entitlements that are not needed by your app and submit an updated binary for review, including the following:

com.apple.developer.maps

Next Steps

For links to essential video and documentation to learn how to sandbox your application, please see App Sandboxing.

Should you need code-level assistance implementing sandboxing, contact Apple Developer Technical Support.

Comment: `coco` is the wrong tag for your question. I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

When you use **Organizer** to upload an app binary to iTunes Connect, you need to make sure that you use a distribution profile for your application instead of Wild Card (XC in the screenshot below) as WC has the Map entitlement enabled.

[image]

In order to create a distribution profile, go to the Certificate website with your account.  Then click on Distribution at the bottom-left and then select App Store.  After creating a profile, you need to go to Xcode's account page and load your profiles.  These days, Xcode won't reload profiles quickly for a server issue or whatever.  So you need to be patient.

[image]

Comment: after this do i need to enable app sandbox in xcode project?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You mean, disable sandbox and then enable it again after importing the distribution file?  If that's the question, no, I don't think so.

Comment: if i disable app sandbox,it doesn't validate.so i want to know what is need of app sandbox?i dont use anything from app sandbox.

Comment: It's not about whether or not you get something out of it.  It's about protecting the user and containing a malacious thing if the application has such.